# MySql Query to convert columns containing delimeter into rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I need to write a query to select the below table

```
UID | Col A | Col B
123   x;y;z    v;b
```

into the below requirement format.

```
123 , Col A, X
123 , Col A, y
123 , Col A, z
123 , Col B, v
123 , Col B, b
```

Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: Great idea. Don't store data as ; separated items, as you've already noticed it's a mess and will only cause lots of trouble.

Comment: Good idea. But the bad part is I cannot change the structure of the table due to this requirement.

Comment: Tough luck... (Create a view that returns data in the way you have specifed.)

Comment: Yes, I am trying in that way only. But I need approach to do that on how to convert the records

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain, but here is one method:

```
select uid, 'Col A' as col,
       substring_index(substring_index(colA, ';', n.n), ';', -1) as val,
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) n
     on (length(replace(colA, ';', '; ')) - length(colA)) <= n.n + 1
union all
select uid, 'Col B' as col,
       substring_index(substring_index(colB, ';', n.n), ';', -1) as val,
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) n
     on (length(replace(colB, ';', '; ')) - length(colB)) <= n.n + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even though it is not giving exact output but thanks for sharing the idea. I will post the corrected one soon